# Confusion about averages: If a person uses 20 cans of paint in 0.8 days, how can they average 25 cans per day when they have only used 20 cans so far?

Tags: average

I'm confused about averages.

> Say a person uses 20 cans of paint, in 5 days. That would that they use 4 cans of paint per day on average
>
> But if a person uses 20 cans of paint in 0.8 days (current day), does that mean they use 25 cans of paint per day on average?
>
> How does that work, since they have only used 20 cans of paint up to that point in the day?

Comment: As you are noticing, it's one thing to interpolate values between known data points and quite another to extrapolate data out of the experimental range.  That $25$ might be absurd...possibly the person actually intends to sleep for the remaining $.2$ of a day.  To extrapolate data you need to model the situation...you can't reliably do it from the numbers alone.

Comment: Average = (Total used)/(total days).   If total days is a fraction and less than 1 it doesn't matter.  It is presumed if the continue using paint at that rate it will be $25$ cans in that day.

Comment: yes, you are correct. By saying "uses 20 cans of paint in 0.8 days", we think of that as "using 1 can of paint in 0.04 days" so every 0.04 days, 1 can of paint gets used. That's how averaging works: we have some sort of total amount and total time, and we divide to find the ratio ASSUMING UNIFORMITY.

Comment: Could you identify what confuses you?  Is it that an average is larger than a total?  Consider this.  We measure how how many cans of paint you used in 40 weeks and it is $800$ cans.  So we figure the average is $20$ cans a week on average.  Then we figure that is $1040$ cans a year.  Would you feel comfortable saying that the person uses $1040$ cans a year on average?  Is this the same, or different than you $20$ cans in $.8$ days?  Why or why not?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).